# "You" as an indefinite pronoun in a first-person statement

Tags: grammaticality

> But like most young people of my generation, waking up 6 am in the
>   morning to study things **you** do not understand, is not an idea that
>   appeals to me

Is my usage of 'you' in this context wrong? It sounds weird, but it doesn't sound right when I replace it with 'I' and 'We' either.

EDIT: It's wrong either way right? Is it better if I replace the whole phrase with

> waking up 6 am in the morning to study incomprehensible things,
>   is not..

Comment: there shouldn't be a comma after _understand_. As for _you_, who's that? Isn't it the same person referred to as _me_? Why do both? Stick with one. _Waking up 6 am in the morning to study things I/you don't/one doesn't understand is not an idea that appeals_.

Comment: As John points out; *one doesn't understand* instead of *you don't understand* has a greater appeal, if I may. At the end of the day it all boils down to context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a grammatical name for the third-person 'you'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/341988/is-there-a-grammatical-name-for-the-third-person-you)

Answer (score 1):

The *you* in that sentence is called a [**generic** or **impersonal you**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_you). It is very common in English and normally isn't confusing at all. It is used for statements which have no specific person but which are generally true for everyone. It's often used for proverbs or wise statements. Some examples are:

- Brushing **your** teeth is important
- Get to the bus stop earlier if **you** don't want to be late
- **You** don't want to miss the next episode of **your** favourite TV show!

The example sentence may seem odd, but it makes sense if you think of it in this way. The *you* in the sentence isn't really referring either to the speaker or to their listener, but is an example of a *generic you*. The sentence has an embedded statement inside of it. If you rephrase it this way (oh look, that was another generic you!) it will be clear how to interpret it:

> "Waking up 6 am in the morning to study things you don't understand" - Like most young people of my generation that's not an idea that appeals to me

The sentence in the question is very natural and very idiomatic. Rephrasing it to avoid *you* will make the sentence less natural. There's no need to do that!

(But I would recommend more contractions.)

Answer (score -1):

> 'But like most young people of my generation, waking up 6 am in the
>   morning to study ... is ...'

is wrong because it coordinates the uncoordinatable: the process of waking up, and most young people of 'my' generation. A rewrite is necessary; here are two suggestions:

> But like most students of my generation, waking up at 6 am in the
>   morning to study things they do not understand, John often wonders why
>   he enrolled on his university course.

Here, 'waking up at 6 am in the morning to study things they do not understand' modifies 'most students of my generation' and gives the reason for John's dissatisfaction.

> But as is true for most young people of my generation, waking up at 6
>   am in the morning to study things they do not understand is not an
>   idea that would appeal to me.

Here, 'waking up at 6 am in the morning to study things they do not understand' is the subject of the main clause.

Answer (score -1):

> But, like most young people of my generation, waking up at 6 am in the morning to study things you do not understand is not an idea that appeals to me.

To trim this down a bit:

> But waking up at 6 am in the morning to study things you do not understand is not an idea that appeals to me.
>
> Waking up to study things you do not understand is not an idea that appeals to me.

The heart of the issue is the difference between "you" and "me". This particular usage isn't *wrong* but it is slightly awkward. A comparable example:

> Finding the house where you live is difficult for me.

The reader is left wondering who "you" is. It is more clear in your sentence that "you" is "me" since people don't often speak about learning things someone *else* doesn't understand but it would be much less confusing if you used "I":

> Waking up to study things **I** do not understand is not an idea that appeals to me.

Expanding this back into the original form:

> But waking up at 6 am in the morning to study things I do not understand is not an idea that appeals to me.
>
> But, like most young people of my generation, waking up at 6 am in the morning to study things I do not understand is not an idea that appeals to me.

At this level, you *could* use "we" but it will have a much more drastic effect:

> But, like most young people of my generation, waking up at 6 am in the morning to study things we do not understand is not an idea that appeals to me.

This shifts the meaning of the sentence to imply that "me" does not want to study things "my generation" does not know. I don't think this was the intended meaning, however, so I would stick with "I".

Of note, you *could* use "one":

> But, like most young people of my generation, waking up at 6 am in the morning to study things one does not understand is not an idea that appeals to me.

And "you" could mean something roughly similar to this but I recommend sticking with "I" as it is the least ambiguous.